# How setup iLO remotely

Tags: vmware-esxi, ilo

I was used to configure HP iLO from Windows OS using hponcnfg, but how it can be done when operating system is ESXi 4.1 without phisically connect to the iLO port (aka remotely)?

Thank you all for help

Comment: what is it you want to configure?

Comment: IP address, network mask, default gateway, admin password. Server mainboard was changed because of a failure so ilo has to be reconfigured from scratch :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this via ESXi - it doesn't support third party applications that can do this type of thing. At a minimum you will have to enable iLO and give it an ip-address by physically doing so at the machine initially.

ESXi is IPMI aware and does support remote management via WBEM which can talk to the embedded hardware management components (BMC\iLO etc) so it may be possible to do this via something like HP SIM but I've never seen an example.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done once the hpilo and hponcfg vibs have been loaded [as per this HP document](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03400101&jumpid=em_alerts_us-us_Jul12_xbu_all_all_1838436_121938_proliantservers_routine_013_4).

Answer (score 2):

If it's a one-off job I'd try to get someone on-site to set it up locally (didn't HP reinstate settings when they swapped out the part? they always do for us). I'd then work on a very small linux bootable ISO with the linux version of hponcfg installed so you can boot into that and do what you like.

Comment: nice idea but I can't mount the iso image without remote iLO access :-(

Comment: good point, well made... it's a trip to site for you then sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the Compaq Light-Outs config utility:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-0fcb2f1331034568b60b4061f1&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&

This basically works the same as HPONCFG, except you are able to specify iLO interface addresses. If you are wanting to update batches of iLO interfaces, then I've made some powershell scripts for that.

http://practicaladmin.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/ilo-bulk-updater-v3-0-now-with-less-perl/

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't see how this helps in the case of ESXi.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I had scripts to update under linux (RHEL4 and 5), and there was the windows stuff, but updating esx4 wasn't possible without rebooting to install the software, and if I had to reboot anyway, I might as well just configure from the bios screen.

Comment: Argh, my bad, I read the first sentance as still configuring the iLOs using windows, but needing to do it remotely, instead of from the same host.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, there is a better approach to this.

If you have used the HP version of EXSi, then the HP drivers are automatically installed and you should able to see various additional hardware listed in the Hardware Tab.

You can also install the HP drivers seperately via VUM.

Once correct drivers are in place, you should see Baseboard Management Controller.

Easiest way to do this is copy the hponcfg file, edit that file and copy back.

1) Connect locally or via SSH

2) Copy config file

```
/opt/hp/tools # ./hponcfg -w ilo.xml
HP Lights-Out Online Configuration utility
Version 4.0-10 (c) Hewlett-Packard Company, 2011
Firmware Revision = 1.81 Device type = iLO 2 Driver name = hpilo
Management Processor configuration is successfully written to file "ilo.xml"
```

3) Edit the XML with desired parameters (login credentials, IP address, Subnet Mask, DNS Name, DHCP Enable/Disable & Domain Name)

4) Overwrite config file

```
/opt/hp/tools # ./hponcfg -f ilo.xml
HP Lights-Out Online Configuration utility
Version 4.0-10 (c) Hewlett-Packard Company, 2011
Firmware Revision = 1.81 Device type = iLO 2 Driver name = hpilo
<INFORM>Integrated Lights-Out will reset at the end of the script.</INFORM>

Please wait while the firmware is reset. This might take a minute    
Script succeeded
```

The above may take more then a minute, so don't panic!

Comment: Note: It's not even necessary to use the HP-specific ESXi build. You can [add the two necessary packages to an existing ESXi installation very easily](http://serverfault.com/a/472930/13325) and obtain the same functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You may use Hponcfg scripts which can be used for this purpose

Comment: Can you provide more information?